# Android NDK: No rule to make target

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm trying to build a simple Android application using NDK.
Here are the contents of my Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)  

include $(CLEAR_VARS)  

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog  

LOCAL_MODULE    := myNDK
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And when I'm running ndk-build I get:

> make: *** No rule to make target
>   `'/native.c', needed by`
>   '/Users/ivan/Documents/workspace/TestNDK/obj/local/armeabi/objs/myNDK/native.o'.
>   Stop.

So the problem is obviously that make is searching the source files in the root directory and if I copy native.c to my root folder everything works perfectly.

The question is: what should I specify in my Android.mk to set the LOCAL_PATH to my working jni folder.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

OK, I've solved my issue, and the reason was very strange:
the problem is in the first line

> 'LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)____'

It had several spaces in the end (I've replaced them with '_'). If you remove them everything works just fine.

Comment: Yes, it definitely helped someone! My hair thanks you (I was about to start pulling it in frustration)! :)

Comment: Good catch! It would be nice to report this as an Android bug, since it still occurs with the NDK revision 7.

Comment: I really wonder how this happens! Thanks a ton for the solution!

Comment: Don't know about you but I copy pasted from a tutorial which obviously contains some sneaky white space. Good catch.

Comment: Great catch. helped me a lot. Thanlks

Comment: Unbelievable, This is a bug of Android NDK. It taked me some unnecessary days. -1 to ANDROID

Comment: I submitted a bug report:   https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42841

Comment: Retardation beyond belief.. Punishing developers for the most inexplicable reason ever.. definitely -1 to Android

Answer (score 2):

On Mac OS X using android-ndk-r9 64 bit, remove white spaces from the NDK path. That fixed the *No rule to make target* error for me

Not exactly an answer for OP, but I guess it can save others from wasting their time.

Answer (score 2):

Another problem that I found that causes this error is that the

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native.c
```

and

```
LOCAL_MODULE    := native
```

use the same name.  I'm not sure why this causes an error, as the code should be generated in different locations as native.o, native.od, and native.  But, apparently it does.

I found this out while trying to compile hello.c to hello.  Once I changed hello.c to main.c, everything compiled properly.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure LOCAL_PATH is at the top of the Android.mk else it won't work due to GNU Compiler syntax

## Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)  
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
```

Also can have ifeq/endif prior to this if need the ndk-major-at-least shorten path or function defines

Answer (score 0):

If there are any syntax error in Android.mk file, no rule to make target error will be there.

I had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue when there is a spelling mistake in the root directory name.

Example: 
My path should have been:

```
 include $(phone-root-dir)/test/test.mk
```

but there is spelling mistake as shown

```
include $(lphone-root-dir)/test/test.mk
```

Once I corrected spelling mistake it worked fine.