# Not able to read audio streams with ffmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-audiomanager, libavcodec, libavformat

I am trying to solve a big problem but stuck with very small issue. I am trying to read audio streams inside a video file with the help of ffmpeg but the loop that should traverse the whole file of streams only runs couple of times. Can not figure out what is the issue as others have used it very similarly.
Following is my code please check:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_ru_dzakhov_ffmpeg_test_MainActivity_logFileInfo
    (JNIEnv * env,
     jobject this,
     jstring filename
    )
{

AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx;
int             i,j,k, videoStream, audioStream;
AVCodecContext  *pCodecCtx; 
AVCodec         *pCodec;
AVFrame         *pFrame; 
AVPacket        packet;
int             frameFinished;
float           aspect_ratio;
AVCodecContext  *aCodecCtx;
AVCodec         *aCodec;
//uint8_t inbuf[AUDIO_INBUF_SIZE + FF_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE];
j=0;

av_register_all();
char *str = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, filename, 0);
 LOGI(str);
// Open video file
if(av_open_input_file(&pFormatCtx, str, NULL, 0, NULL)!=0)
    ;

// Retrieve stream information
if(av_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx)<0)
    ;

 LOGI("Separating");
// Find the first video stream  
videoStream=-1;
audioStream=-1;

for(i=0; i<&pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++) {

    if(pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type==AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO)
    {
        LOGI("Audio Stream");
        audioStream=i;
        }
}
av_write_header(pFormatCtx);
if(videoStream==-1)
     LOGI("Video stream is -1");    


if(audioStream==-1)
     LOGI("Audio stream is -1");

return i;}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may be having issue related to library loading and unloading and how that relates to repeated calls thru jni. Not sure from what your symptom is , but if u have no solution try reading :

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649119/calling-native-method-twice-of-third-party-library-in-an-activity-causes-the-and)

and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898338/android-video-trimming-via-ffmpeg)