# Loading JNI library in another JNI library crashes

Tags: android, java-native-interface, jniwrapper

I'm essentially trying to follow a SO solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649119/calling-native-method-twice-of-third-party-library-in-an-activity-causes-the-and), but am running into a problem.

This is essentially what I am doing fron inside a JNI library:

```
handle = dlopen("/data/data/lib/my.package/lib/myLibrary.so", RTLD_LAZY);
myFunctionName = (func)dlsym(handle, "main");
(*myFunctionName)(numberOfArgs, arguments);
```

The problem is that the above ONLY succeeds if

```
System.loadLibrary("myLibrary")
```

is called from the same Java code invoking the JNI. But this obviously defeats the purpose of loading the library via dlopen.

All I get from LocCat is

```
A/libc(29472): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1)
```

What is going wrong? Is it something to do with the build parameters for myLibrary.so?

Comment: Just to know, why would you want to load a library in native code with dlopen instead of using System.loadLibrary?

Comment: To address this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649119/calling-native-method-twice-of-third-party-library-in-an-activity-causes-the-and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using dlerror() to diagnose the problem, I actually found that dlopen was failing.
Turns the path was wrong. It should be:

```
handle = dlopen("/data/data/my.package/lib/myLibrary.so", RTLD_LAZY);
```