# Android NDK and Gradle plugin 0.7: make: *** No rule to make target

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

It looks that since Android Gradle Plugin 0.7 there is NDK support.

But I'm having trouble configuring it...

Error looks similar to this question: [Android NDK: No rule to make target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243047/android-ndk-no-rule-to-make-target) but it is different.

Because as [user2359247](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2359247/user2359247) stated, that `ndk-build` looks for `BitmapBlur.c` in unexpected location.

When executing assemble task I get error:

```
/opt/android-ndk-r8e/ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=/home/martynas/app/application/build/ndk/flavor/release/Android.mk APP_PLATFORM=android-18 NDK_OUT=/home/martynas/app/application/build/ndk/flavor/release/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=/home/martynas/app/application/build/ndk/flavor/release/lib APP_ABI=all
  Error Code:
    2
  Output:
    make: *** No rule to make target `/home/martynas/app/application/build/ndk/flavor/release//home/martynas/app/application/src/main/jni/BitmapBlur.c', needed by `/home/martynas/app/application/build/ndk/flavor/release/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/application//home/martynas/app/application/src/main/jni/BitmapBlur.o'.  Stop.
```

Project structure:

```
app
   application
      src/main/java
      src/main/jni
          Android.mk
          BitmapBlur.c
          BitmapBlur.h
```

My Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := BitmapBlur
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := BitmapBlur.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -ljnigraphics

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

My build.gradle does not have any particular configuration related to NDK.

What am I doing wrong? All android-ndk samples shows similar configuration.

Comment: Nope, checked that. No trailing spaces. And when building module manually this configuration works.

Comment: If you look closely, you will see that BitmapBlur.c is looked in a wrong directory, probably your NDK directory merged with your app directory. Which version of NDK are you using?

Comment: Yeah, I see that. But why? I'm using Revision 8e.

Comment: I found a sollution. I had to update my `build.gradle` `defaultConfig` with `ndk` configuration. And remove `Android.mk` from `src/main/jni`

Comment: I would rather switch to NDK 9. There is a known bug about source paths in NDK 8.

Comment: Yeah, forgot to mention, that I switched to NDK revision 9b + changes mentioned in previous comment.