# Android NDK Error :

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

[image]

Facing below waring while executing Android based NDK application:

```
Warning:
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-19 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 8 in ./AndroidManifest.xml"
```

After this warning nothing happens in process. Am I doind anything wrong.

Any body please guide I am new in Android as well in NDK development. Is there any other easy way to do the same to access CPP libraries in Android.

Comment: I think it is cause of second error it is being aborted. `No rule to make target` . Check if that file is added in Android.mk

Comment: are you sure the file `e:\Work\MyExamples\AndroidExamples\SasmpleNDKProject\jni\squarewrapper.c` exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minSdkVersion in `AndroidManifest.xml` and in `Application.mk` have to be the same. Change your `APP_PLATFORM := android-19` to `APP_PLATFORM := android-8` in `Application.mk` warning will disapear.

Comment: Maybe this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243047/android-ndk-no-rule-to-make-target

Answer (score 1):

Execute ndk-build from the actual project directory. Lets say you are trying to build one of the samples execute ndk-build from this directory /samples/hello-jni. This should build the project.
Also add ndk-build path to PATH variable like this
set path=%path%;

Ignore the warning. it just means that your target-platform is greater than your minSDkversion  Which is usually the case.