# android custom build. adding an app to the build

Tags: android, makefile, android-ndk, custom-build

i want to make a custom build of android by editing the code of android.
The main motive is to adding and removing apps from the build.
Removing an app from the build is pretty simple. i just deleted its entry from the core.mk file.

but now i want to add my application to the build. every time i get make error.

```
make: *** No rule to make target `packages/apps/MyApplication/AndroidManifest.xml', needed by `out/target/product/generic/obj/APPS/MyApplication_intermediates/package.apk'.  Stop.
```

need help for the following topics

1. how do i write makefile for my application. its just a helloworld app (for first experiment).
2. do i need to add entry for the application anywhere else than the build/target/product/core.mk file.
3. what this error refers to. and what is the solution.

Comment: This error looks similar to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243047/android-ndk-no-rule-to-make-target

Comment: i have already taken reference from the given link... but it is not helping

Comment: do android studio project structure can be a problem. i was observing that all the apps in packages/apps/ have directory structure according to elipse